# Como definir tabela que receberá o insert usando variável PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho algumas tabelas que seguem um padrão:

> NomeUsuário_SobreomeUsuário_IDUsuário_sementes
>   Jefferson_Carlos_1_sementes
>   Carlos_Drummond_2_sementes

o nome, sobrenome e ID ficam armazenados na sessão e recupero para fazer a inserção no banco de dados:

```
$ID         = $_SESSION['ID'];
$nome       = $_SESSION['nome'];
$sobrenome  = $_SESSION['sobrenome'];
```

Depois recupero os dados informados pelo usuário:

```
$ano        = $_POST['ano'];
$mes        = $_POST['mes'];
$titulo     = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao  = $_POST['descricao'];
```

A query fica desta forma (ou pelo menos gostaria que fosse):

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO '$nome'_'$sobrenome'_'$ID'_sementes(ano, mes, titulo, descricao) VALUES ('$ano', '$mes', '$titulo', '$descricao') ";
```

Dei um echo na query para ver como ficou (obviamente não foi executada corretamente):

> INSERT INTO 'Jefferson'*'Carlos'*'1'_sementes(ano, mes, titulo,
>   descricao) VALUES ('2017', 'Julho', 'titulo exemplo', 'descrição
>   exemplo')

Se eu retirar os ' :

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO $nome_$sobrenome_$ID_sementes(ano, mes, titulo, descricao) VALUES ('$ano', '$mes', '$titulo', '$descricao') ";
```

dá esse erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: nome_ in
>   /storage/emulated/0/www/registra_semente.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: sobrenome_ in
>   /storage/emulated/0/www/registra_semente.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ID_sementes in
>   /storage/emulated/0/www/registra_semente.php on line 23

E a query imprime assim:

> INSERT INTO (ano, mes, titulo,
>   descricao) VALUES ('2017', 'Julho', 'titulo exemplo', 'descrição
>   exemplo')

**O que eu faço?**

Comment: Tu usa uma tabela pra cada usuario?

Comment: Sim, pois cada usuário insere muitos dados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente concatenar a string dessa maneira:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO $nome"."_"."$sobrenome"."_"."$ID_sementes(ano, mes, titulo, descricao) VALUES ('$ano', '$mes', '$titulo', '$descricao') ";
```

Comment: Mano, deu certinho, VLW MESMO

Comment: De nada, se puder aceitar a resposta, agradece!

Comment: Demorei aceitar pq não dava, falava que eu tinha que esperar... mas agora está tudo certo, vlw novamente.

Comment: Sem problemas, por nada.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro de tudo, verifique as variáveis que recebem o valor da Sessão antes de tentar fazer o `insert`, vai evitar um bom estresse no futuro. Depois pode concatenar o nome da tabela:

```
$tabela = $nome."_".$sobrenome."_".$ID_sementes;
$sql = "INSERT INTO '".$tabela."'(ano, mes, titulo, descricao) VALUES ('".$ano."', '".$mes."', '".$titulo."', '".$descricao."')";
```

Comment: Vlw pela atenção amigo.